# Why cv2.namedWindow is not works?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, pycharm

I try start my code, but process finishes on step with method cv2.namedWindow (without
any errors).
Do you have any suggestions, why it could be so?

```
import cv2


image_cv2 = cv2.imread('/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/python_snippets/external_data/girl.jpg')


def viewImage(image, name_of_window):
    print('step_1')
    cv2.namedWindow(name_of_window, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    print('step_2')
    cv2.imshow(name_of_window, image)
    print('step_3')
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print('step_4')
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cropped = image_cv2
viewImage(cropped, 'Cropped version')
```

P.S.:
Also I erased UBUNTU , and installed Fedora.
Instead Pycharm, check programm on VS code.
But nothing changes.
I changed location for picture (girl.jpg) to directory with python document.
But program stops on step1 and waiting something.
[image: test_other_direct]

Comment: You are getting a segmentation fault error (SIGSEGV) probably when calling `cv2.imshow`. Does this path exist: `/home/spartak/PycharmProjects/python_base/lesson_016/python_snippets/external_data/girl.jpg`?

Comment: Please use the Stack Overflow editor tool [to upload images](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) instead of hosting them on external services.

Comment: Actually your code works fine on my envşronment. Can you try to run it without `namedWindow` line ?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes, exist. I changed location for jpg, but nothing chages.  ![Valid XHTML](https://ic.wampi.ru/2021/11/09/SNIMOK-EKRANA-OT-2021-11-09-19-17-49.png)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Tried without namedWindow. Python waiting after step2. 
![Valid XHTML](https://ic.wampi.ru/2021/11/09/SNIMOK-EKRANA-OT-2021-11-09-19-42-21.png)

Comment: can you reproduce this on any other computer? if not, it's an issue with your specific system. explain your system. what is installed, how was it installed, how do you run your code? I'm betting you run this in some container or something... don't do that. that's often more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @SpartakBorisov, try debugging, try placing a `pause()` or similar function inside viewImage after calling `namedWindow` or `imshow` and see if there is a window which is created and if an image is displayed there.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem.
I started this code in virtual environment.
Apparently, in virtual environment on UBUNTU/FEDORA, opencv have restrictions.

[image: Final_version]

Answer (score -1):

The code completes all 4 steps for me

I think there is a problem with the image path which you took

[image]

The function cv2.namedWindow creates a window that can be used as a placeholder for images and trackbars. Created windows are referred to by their names If a window with the same name already exists, the function does nothing.

Comment: I tried absolute path and just filename.Changed location for this jpg to directory with python program. Nothing changed. Here screen: https://ibb.co/Lg9cZpT

Comment: @SpartakBorisov try giving `imread` just `girl.jpg` as input.

Comment: check the path **...../python_base/lesson_016/python_snippets/girl.jpg**

you can just give **girl.jpg** because the code and the image were in the same directory.

Comment: No relation with the image path and the problem !!!

Comment: @DNy I choose just 'imread('girl.jpg')' , but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DNy ![Valid XHTML](https://ic.wampi.ru/2021/11/09/SNIMOK-EKRANA-OT-2021-11-09-19-17-49.png)

Answer (score -1):

I do think the function
[cv2.destroyAllWindows](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=destroyallwindows#destroyallwindows)
This function is deallocating some needed gui elements, I would guess.
So calling this multiple times will produce some trouble.

```
import cv2

image_cv2 =  cv2.imread('foo.jpg')
def viewImage(image, name_of_window):
    print('step_1')
    cv2.namedWindow(name_of_window)
    print('step_2')
    cv2.imshow(name_of_window, image)
    print('step_3')
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    #print('step_4')
    #cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    

cropped = image_cv2
viewImage(cropped, 'Cropped version')
#e.g. better usage at the end of the code or section 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I did it, python stops after step2 and waiting something

Comment: you can call destroyAllWindows as often as you like. it'll merely destroy all windows, not prevent new ones from being created.